# WPF style for buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I haven't used WPF for a very long time (close to 4 years). But now started to use it again for some usage, you can see one of my top asked questions is in WPF. The reason I mention is this because I do have some knowledge about WPF and how it works. My latest project invovlves using BLEND to achieve a very good UI.
So here I have a Photoshop layout, and I am trying to get this layout design,

[image]

And so far I only have this,

[image]

So really would appreciate if someone could point me on the following things.

How to get the border glow effect and curves also how to group them to a particular style in a separate file and link it to the buttons. Thanks for your time and answers

EDIT: With my styles code.

I have the following styles code in Custom_Styles.xaml (Resource dictionary)
How do I link it to the button?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Keyboard_actual">

    <Style x:Key="Button" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" Stroke="#60000000" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ hey no worries bro.. tks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the border glow effect, you can add a [Drop Shadow Effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect(v=vs.110).aspx) with a `Shadow Depth` of 0 and the desired color and a border brush of white for the Button.

To create the style in a separate file, you need to create a Resource Dictionary like this:

**Project** ► **Add New Item...** ► **Resource Dictionary**

Then name your file. In this example, I name it `Styles.xaml`.

Now open up your App.xaml and put this within the `Application` tag:

```xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--Put all previous resources in the App.xaml here-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now in the Styles.xaml file within the `ResourceDictionary` tag, put the style. I am working on a style too. Once I finish it I will post it.

To link the style, use:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Button}" .../>
```

It may not work since the key is "Button". If it doesn't change it to something like "ButtonStyle".

And the Drop Shadow Effect does a pretty decent job.

Here's an example (Zoomed at 200%):

[image: QWERTY]

and the XAML style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF00C3BA"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0.8" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF72FFE5" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

used like this:

```
<Grid Background="#FF171717">
    <Button Content="Q" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="103,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="Y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="378,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="T" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="323,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="R" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="268,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="213,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="W" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="158,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So this resources dictionary can contain multiple styles? and not only one right? cause as u can see from my photoshop image I need to have multiple sizes of the buttons

Comment: Yes infinite styles. But you can just set the width of each button. Why create so many styles. It might decrease performance.

Comment: I meant one for the top row all the esc  - f12 buttons and then for the other alphabets.

Comment: Is it possible to show me how to get that effect on the button as I showed up top. Tks.

Comment: Hi, not to bother was wondering is that is all the anwer you are going to offer?

Comment: You can't expect anyone here to offer you complete styles. However I will post a sample.

Comment: Thankyou! wasn't expecting so.. but some guideline is great.. tks

Comment: Is there any way of animating this and adding a hover and click effect?

Comment: @Mrbisquit See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757498/color-transition-in-a-buttons-hover-effect-using-a-style-in-wpf