# Color transition in a button's hover effect using a style in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, colors

I just recently started in WPF and I'm trying to replace the default hover effect of a buttton using a style I made.

```
<Style x:Key="UserType_LoginButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid" From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
A value of type 'Event Trigger' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection'
```

How can I add the event trigger then?

Comment: add EventTrigger inside `<Style.Triggers>` tag

Comment: @ASh I received another error again `'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `VisualState` for your `ControlTemplate` to your button. Like,

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="testButtonTemplate2">
    <Border Name="RootElement">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="Black"/>
        </Border.Background>

        <Grid Margin="4" >
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBackground" Color="Aquamarine"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="4,5,4,4"/>
        </Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Your button will be

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource testButtonTemplate2}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
Foreground="White">My button</Button>
```

Ref. [How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)

Answer (score -1):

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "White" />
    <Setter Property = "Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For over hover effect only.

Comment: How do you change the background with a custom color?